# Google Apps Script - Import Contacts from CSV with trigger - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

wann Import Contacts from a CSV File with Google Apps Script
the CSV File is stored on Google Drive.

I found this example:

But did not work for me:

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.csv').next();
  Logger.log(file.getSize());
  Logger.log(file.getName());
  Logger.log(file.getDateCreated());
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

got this error:

14:45:50
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
14:45:51
Info
1624.0
14:45:51
Info
file.csv
14:45:51
Info
Fri Sep 17 11:51:35 GMT+02:00 2021
14:45:51
Fehler
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null
importCSVFromGoogleDrive
@ import.gs:9

How to fix this ?

If i set this line:

Logger.log(Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString()));

I can see the content of the CSV file.

15:27:26
Hinweis
Ausführung begonnen
15:27:26
Info
1624.0
15:27:26
Info
file.csv
15:27:26
Info
Fri Sep 17 11:51:35 GMT+02:00 2021
15:27:27
Info

```
[[Name, Given Name, Additional Name, Family Name, Yomi Name, Given Name Yomi, Additional Name Yomi, Family Name Yomi, Name Prefix, Name Suffix, Initials, Nickname, Short Name, Maiden Name, Birthday, Gender, Location, Billing Information, Directory Server, Mileage, Occupation, Hobby, Sensitivity, Priority, Subject, Notes, Language, Photo, Group Membership, E-mail 1 - Type, E-mail 1 - Value, Phone 1 - Type, Phone 1 - Value, Address 1 - Type, Address 1 - Formatted, Address 1 - Street, Address 1 - City, Address 1 - PO Box, Address 1 - Region, Address 1 - Postal Code, Address 1 - Country, Address 1 - Extended Address, Organization 1 - Type, Organization 1 - Name, Organization 1 - Yomi Name, Organization 1 - Title, Organization 1 - Department, Organization 1 - Symbol, Organization 1 - Location, Organization 1 - Job Description, Website 1 - Type, Website 1 - Value], [Anna Musterfrau, Anna, , Musterfrau, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , * myContacts, * Home, anna@musterfrau.de, Mobile, +491234567890, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [Hans Meise, Hans, , Meise, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , * myContacts, * Home, meinse@hans.de, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [Hans Mustermann, Hans, , Mustermann, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , * myContacts, * , hans@mustermann.de, Main, +4912345 98765, , Nebenstrasse 122, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [Musterhausen 12345, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ], [DE", Nebenstrasse 122, Musterhausen, , , 12345, DE, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ]
```

Comment: You can only call `getActiveSheet()` if your code is running within a container, such as a Spreadsheet. In your case it may be that you only have a script file, which is however not related or connected to the Spreadsheet you are working in. Can you confirm this assumption, namely that your script is not bound to the Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you run this script?

on https://script.google.com/home with "execude"

the script should run automated with a trigger
so that the contacts will add every day from the CSV file
a script to delete all conacts I found an this work.
But need to add the contacts from CSV file...

Contacts-Source is CSV File, automated import with apps script
every day by using a trigger

Plan is: CSV -->  direct Google Contacts Import with Apps Script by using a trigger

Comment: _on https://script.google.com/home with "execude"_ - this is where the error comes from. Your script is not linked to Google Sheet. You can either create a [new spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/) and [paste your script into it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=ru#creating_a_custom_function), or you need to refer to the spreadsheet via [ID](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=ru#openById(String)) - `SpreadsheetApp.openById('... sheet ID...').getSheetByName('... sheet name...')`

Comment: Open new empty spreadsheet. Open Tools > Script Editor. Paste your script inside the editor. Click the button "Run". Give the access and permissions. See results on the spreadsheet.